# runing async function like sync in node js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I get problems, when I try to execute two async function.
This is my first function that download images in specific folders.

```
const getLayerData = async (Collection_id) => {
  let layers_data = await getLayersID(Collection_id);
  //let collection_name = await getcollecionName(Collection_id);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    layers_data.forEach((value, key) => {    
      getTraitData(key, value);
    });
    console.log('finish downloading layers');

  });  
};
```

My second function allow it to resize images, modified and upload it to firestore.

To run both, I read states in the firestore to do tasks. When it runs, only one async is execute.

```
const start = async () => {
  var users = await readStates();
  var task = users.length;
  while (true) {
    
    if (task > 0){
      users.forEach(data => { 

        // download layers

        buildSetup(); //sync
        getLayerData(data[1)]; //async 
        startCreating(); //async allow resize, modify, upload to firestore, storage
         
        
        //espera (data);
        //runTask();

        //end task processs
        task = task - 1;

      });
    }else{
      //console.log(task);
      break;
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: I am trying to understand this better. Shouldn't the `startCreating` happen only after `getLayerData(data[1])` is fulfilled?

Comment: For starters, wrapping something inside of `return new Promise(...)` where you never resolve or reject the promise will not solve any problem.  In fact, all it does is return a promise that never fulfills in any way.  That accomplishes nothing.  The code inside your promise executor is not affected at all by being inside the promise executor.  It runs just the same as it would if it wasn't inside the promise executor.  To make use of a custom created promise, you need to call `resolve(val)` or `reject(err)` when the asynchronous operation is complete.

Comment: @thefourtheye  yes, but right now the function `getLayerData(data[1])` finish their process and start with `startingCreating`. The problem is that the last one continue reading the layer folder as empty one and it doesn't modificate the images.